# Scraping: How to fetch an attribute in a <abbr> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am using **lxml and python** to scrape through a page. The link to the page is **[HERE](http://www.insiderpages.com/b/3721895833/central-kia-of-irving-irving)**. The hiccup I face right now is how to fetch the attribute in the  tag. For example the 3 Gold stars at the top of the page, they have a html

```
<abbr title="3" class="average rating large star3">★★★☆☆</abbr>
```

Here I want to fetch the title so that I know how many stars did this location get.

I have tried doing a couple of things including this:

```
response = urllib.urlopen('http://www.insiderpages.com/b/3721895833/central-kia-of-irving-irving').read()
mo = re.search(r'<div class="rating_box">.*?</div>', response)
div = html.fromstring(mo.group(0))
title = div.find("abbr").attrib["title"]
print title
```

But does not work for me. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use regex to extract data from html.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/843822) You have lxml, use it's power ([XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath)).

```
>>> import lxml.html as html
>>> page = html.parse("http://www.insiderpages.com/b/3721895833/central-kia-of-irving-irving")
>>> print page.xpath("//div[@class='rating_box']/abbr/@title")
['3']
```

Comment: Yours is better. I didn't know lxml can fetch pages itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried xpath?

```
In [38]: from lxml import etree

In [39]: import urllib2

In [40]: html = etree.fromstring(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.insiderpages.com/b/3721895833/central-kia-of-irving-irving').read(), parser)

In [41]: html.xpath('//abbr')[0].xpath('./@title')
Out[41]: ['3']
```